# meta view port in PC and Android difference

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm starting with responsive with `HTML5` / `CSS3`. I'm stuck with one thing: I understand without problems what needs to be done for the resolution to load a `CSS` or another using media queries.

I do:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minim- 
scale=1 maximum-scale=1" /
<link href="estilosGranResolucion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
media="screen and (min-width: 700px)"/>
```

Well, in chrome with developer option in a PC, I see that perfect, at 700 pixels in width of the window, the aspect changes. Well, if I try it on a PC mobile emulator, the opera mobile emulator, I see that it does not change until 1049 exactly.

And if I put "min-width: 600px" it does not change up to 899 pixels. (in the mobile emulator)

And if I put "min-width: 1000px" it does not change up to 1499 pixels. (in the mobile emulator)

In other words, the "offset" that is seen is not even constant. It is as if you always add a quantity to what I put, but the higher the resolution, the more you add before changing.

Why does not it change in the mobile emulator to the resolution that should change and in PC yes?. I have also tried on a normal mobile and it happens the same.

The truth is that I'm stuck with that.

---

It works well on chrome pc, I can see that at 700px change the Css.
But not in opera emulator mobile or a real phone.

In mobile operator the change to the css is done at:

If I put "min-width: 700px" it does not change up to 1049 pixels. (in mobile emulator)

And if I put "min-width: 600px" it does not change up to 899 pixels. (in mobile emulator)

And if I put "min-width: 1000px" it does not change up to 1499 pixels. (in mobile emulator)

It's very strange for me, but it's my first responsive design.

Thanks.

And another problem, if I use the emulator it works, if i put the emulator in horizontal, I can see that the design changes to responsive, but in the real mobile it does not change!. And the emulator is in full HD just like the real mobile.

The web is:

instituto-torreblanca.000webhostapp.com

The menu changes from vertical to horizontal at a concrete resolution, but it doesn't work on real mobile full HD.

EDIT:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Sorry, i see now that for code is neccesary 4 white spaces. Now you can see the code. And fixed in the first post too.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height = device-height, 
target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minim- 
scale=1 maximum-scale=1" />



<link href="estilosGranResolucion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
media="screen and (min-width: 1000px)"/>
<link href="estilosMedianaResolucion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
media="screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 999px)"/>
```

It works well on chrome pc, i can see that at 700px change the Css. But not in opera emulator mobile or a real phone.

In mobile operator the change to the css is done at:

If I put "min-width: 700px" it does not change up to 1049 pixels. (in mobile emulator)

And if I put "min-width: 600px" it does not change up to 899 pixels. (in mobile emulator)

And if I put "min-width: 1000px" it does not change up to 1499 pixels. (in mobile emulator)

It's very strange for me, but it's my first responsive design.

Thanks.

And another problem, if i use the emulator it works, if i put the emulator in horozontal, i can see that the design changes to responsive, but in the real mobile it does not change!. And the emulator is in full hd just like the real mobile.

The web is:

instituto-torreblanca.000webhostapp.com

The menú changes from vertical to horizontal at a concrete resolution, but it doesn't work on real mobile full hd.

EDIT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.

I can see how the function is different if the browser in the real mobile is with "desktop" option or not. The width=device-width works different in each mode.

I don't know what to do.

Before a lot of test, i can see that 1 mobile pixel is not 1 pixel in the meta tags.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in case people want to test out your code.

Comment: Have you tried `initial-scale=1`?

Comment: Yes, if you see my code you can see that it's that. Now the complete sentence is:  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height = device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minim-scale=1 maximum-scale=1" />

Comment: I see something that it seems to be the key but i don't understand nothing: 

if i add "   $(function(){alert(window.innerWidth);  
          alert(window.devicePixelRatio);
       alert(window.outerWidth);})  "           

I get:                                 

In chrome PC: 1152     1      1152
In opera mobile emulator (i put in 1000 width):  667  1.5  1000
In chrome android (1080x1920): 360   3     360

Comment: I know that the metadata info is the problem, it's the reason because it is working bad on my telephone. I think i have the problem but not the solution. 360x3 = 1080. But how can i say to html5 that get the true width?.

Comment: The devicePixelRatio is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the initial scale at the end, you may have to play with the number a little bit. 
EX>

You can also try minimum-scale and/or maximum-scale.

It might also be the device you are using.

Comment: It has been tested in some devices, the result are the same. Never get the other Css for more than 1000 pixels, always get the css for less than 1000 pixels. But in chrome PC works well and in opera mobile emulator too.

Answer (score 0):

1) A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, and `user-scalable` properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

2) Another option, if you would like to try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=.51, maximum-scale=0.51, minimum-scale=0.51"/>
```

3) The small zoom applied by many smartphones by setting the initial scale and minimum-scale values to `0.86`. The result is horizontal scroll is suppressed in any orientation and the user can zoom in if they want to.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.86, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=0.86">
```

Comment: If i put "target-densitydpi=device-dpi" then and only then, it works in opera mobile simulator (in chorme PC works even without that). But in a real mobile phone doesn't work and never uses the css associated with when the resolution exceeds 1000 pixels. Thank you!.

Comment: @user3765208 Make sure you can clear browser's cache.